# ASP.NET Hash List<int>

Tags: asp.net, jquery, hash

I am creating a WebForms application in a ajax call I create a small  List (which can vary in size) that I send back as a JSON object. In the object that I return via JSON I would like to include a hash value to make sure that when I send that list off in the next step, I can check that none of these values have been tampered with. I am using C#'s SHA256 implementation and would like to know the best way to hash this list of integers with a secret key. Any ideas? Thank you again for all of your help and responses.

Comment: You should be using HMAC, otherwise nothing stops me from updating the list and then rehashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness I will let everyone know my solutions as it may help someone in the future.

What I did was since this list of integers represent ID values, I ended up saving these in the database since I was to need them later anyways. This created a one to many association where I then hashed the ID value of the parent record that housed these association records. I used @Cipher comment about using HMAC to make sure that there can't be any tampering of this value. This allows me to store a large list of these items that I would need to be able to retrieve later anyways.

Thank you for your input and hope this may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

may be this helps you in what you are trying to do

[JSON encryption envelope](http://jsonenc.info/1.0/)